# Common size of basic app production bundle

Tags: angular, build, production-environment

I'm trying to build my first Angular 6 app for production, and the build size is around 1 MB.

Because of lack of the experience, it is hard for me to estimate what size it should be, but 1 MB seems to big for relatively small app.

How such an issue can be inspected?

Comment: 1 MB for a small app sounds about right. Depends on your dependencies :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can analyze your bundle size with [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer).

If you're using Angular Cli, then you can build your project with `ng build --prod --stats-json` and it will create a stats.json file inside your `dist` folder.

Then you can run `webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json` and it will show you the problematic areas.